# In the function cartNumbers I am getting this error: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null at cartNumbers

Tags: javascript

```
function cartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers')
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers)

    if(productNumbers){
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1)
        document.querySelector('.cart-span').textContent = productNumbers + 1
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1)
        document.querySelector('.cart-span').textContent = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can only mean `document.querySelector('.cart-span')` returns NULL. Are you sure there is at least one element in your HTML code with the class `cart-span` ?
I hope this will help.

Comment: part of HTML is this: <li class="cart">
                        <a href="cart.html">
                            <i class="fab fa-opencart">Cart</i><span>0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

Comment: So you need to target `<span>0</span>` you should add the class `cart-span` to that `span`. Your code should be `<li class="cart"> <a href="cart.html"> <i class="fab fa-opencart">Cart</i><span class="cart-span">0</span> </a> </li>`